# Use Parenthesis for Negative Numbers in Datagridview Column

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Good Afternoon

I have a column in Datagridview and It looks like this

[image]

As what you see on the image above there negative numbers. How can i change `-` to `()`? For example `5.00` to `(5.00)`?

Comment: how do you fill your field?

Comment: I fill my field using mysql command like this `Variance = PhysicalCount - SystemCount`

Comment: it's a sql server database?

Comment: its a mysql database here is my mysql command `Update physicalinv set Variance = PhysicalCount - SystemCount`

Comment: another question, how do you save the variance value if it's negative? do you save it with minus sign or with parenthesis? to display the value with parenthesis, you can try this in your query : `select case when PhysicalCount-SystemCount<0 then '('+convert(abs(PhysicalCount-SystemCount), varchar)+')' else convert(PhysicalCount-SystemCount) end as Variance`

Comment: It will save the data together with the negative sign i will just used the update command that i comment here

Comment: Dont you think i will use If else in my update command when data is < 0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122379/discussion-between-romulus001-and-nyx-assasin).